# Processing table with comma separated values in different columns

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv

I'm trying to do the following for a while but without success.

The data I received has comma separated values in each separate columns. The first value in column 6 before the comma is always related to the first value in column 7 before the comma. I want to extract data and put them into a table in the right order as such:

Input Data:

```
1 2 3 4 5 A1,A2 B1,B2
1 7 3 3 5 C1,C2,C3 D1,D2,D3
1 2 R 4 b E1,E2,E3,E4 G1,G2,G3,G4
```

Output Data:

```
1 2 3 4 5 A1 B1
1 2 3 4 5 A2 B2
1 7 3 3 5 C1 D1 
1 7 3 3 5 C2 D2
1 7 3 3 5 C3 D3
1 2 R 4 b E1 G1
1 2 R 4 b E2 G2
1 2 R 4 b E3 G3
1 2 R 4 b E4 G4
```

I understand I need to split them by `\t` before placing them into an array of sort, but I'm utterly new to this and having received such huge data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{split($6,a,","); split($7,b,","); for(i in a){print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,a[i],b[i]}}' file
```

- `awk` reads the input space or tab delimited, default: `[\t ]+`.
- `split($6,a,",")` split the 6th field `$6` separated by comma `,` and store the output in an array called `a`.
- `split($7,b,",")` split the 7th field `$7` separated by comma `,` and store the output in an array called `b`.
- `for(i in a)` now loop trough the `a` array...

  - `print ...,a[i],b[i]` ... and print the values `$1` to `$5` and the two array values `a[i]` and `b[i]` by their indexes `i`.

---

The output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 A1 B1
1 2 3 4 5 A2 B2
1 7 3 3 5 C1 D1
1 7 3 3 5 C2 D2
1 7 3 3 5 C3 D3
1 2 R 4 b E1 G1
1 2 R 4 b E2 G2
1 2 R 4 b E3 G3
1 2 R 4 b E4 G4
```

Comment: awesome thanks! this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```c
~$ raku -ne 'my @split1 = .split(/ \s+ /); 
             my @split2 = @split1.[5..*].map: .split(","); 
             for [Z] @split2 { put (@split1[0..4], $_).join("\t") };'  file.txt
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. There are `CSV` modules which will handle complex CSV files (multi-line headers, embedded newlines, etc.). Above is an answer without loading external modules.

The code directs reading of the file linewise, via the `-ne` (non-autoprinting, linewise) flags. The first `split` breaks on whitespace to create array `@split1`. Since 5 "data" columns are given at the start of each row, index `[0..4]` are ignored in the second statement, which `map`s into and `split`s the `[5..*]` latter "covariant" columns of `@split1` (this time splitting on `,` comma), to create `@split2` array.

The `[Z]` prefix Zip-reduction operator takes off each element of the `@split2` array, effectively transposing elements (so that `A1` and `B1` are adjacent, etc.). Finally the row is out`put`, "data" columns and "covariant" columns adjacent, `join`ed as necessary.

Sample Input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 A1,A2 B1,B2
1 7 3 3 5 C1,C2,C3 D1,D2,D3
1 2 R 4 b E1,E2,E3,E4 G1,G2,G3,G4
```

Sample Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5   A1 B1
1 2 3 4 5   A2 B2
1 7 3 3 5   C1 D1
1 7 3 3 5   C2 D2
1 7 3 3 5   C3 D3
1 2 R 4 b   E1 G1
1 2 R 4 b   E2 G2
1 2 R 4 b   E3 G3
1 2 R 4 b   E4 G4
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/split
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Reduction_metaoperators
https://raku.org